# Howto Cisco AnyConnect 2.4 connect without proxy

Tags: cisco, anyconnect

When i start the Cisco AnyConnect the client uses the IE proxy definitions, does anyone knows a way to prevent this?

Can i configure the client to "not use IE proxy definitions" ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set that option in the AnyConnect Client Profile

Proxy Support section:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect24/administration/guide/ac03features.html#wp1069089